# Can I use GeoTools with Gradle?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, java, geotools

I am going to implement shapefile uploading from a webform, and ingestion into PostGIS.

One problem I am having is that my project is using **[Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)** for dependency management.

I am unfamiliar with Gradle and have no idea how to find the right string to get the jars into my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoTools doesn't seem to exist in maven Central (http://mvnrepository.com/) so you would have to add a repository configuration to your build:

```
repositories {
   maven {
     url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/"
   }
 }
```

The syntax for the dependencies is something like:

```
compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-shapefile', version: '11-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2021:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-shapefile', version: '25.0'
}
```

Maven info here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-shapefile?repo=osgeo-release

Comment: Note: I had to add `maven { url = uri("https://nexus.geomatys.com/repository/geotoolkit/") }` before `mavenCentral()` in my `repositories` for geotools to get all its required dependecies